# Using XAMPP as localhost for Java

Tags: java, javafx, xampp

Can I use xampp as a localhost for java or javafx to be specific? You see, I've been looking on the internet and all I see is sqlite which seems so complicated since I just started learning java and still unfamiliar in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP is Application bundle for **PHP**

Comment: Thank you sir. I just thought i can use it in java since i can use it on visual basic too. Hehehe. Maybe I'll just stick on sqlite or whatsoever. Thanks :D

Comment: No, `XAMPP` is not only for `PHP`. You can use  it in `Java` also. Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637071/8226584)